# Проблема заключется в том что не выполняется нормально проверка на тип данных JS

Tags: javascript

```
    const tabel = {
        "biology": 11,
        "phisic": 8,
        "history": 12,
        "mathematic": 6,
        "sport": "3",
        "battle magic": 12,
        name: "Суй",
        "last name": "Рю",
    };
  let overallScore = [];
  let allValues =  Object.values(tabel);
    for(let item of allValues){
        if (typeof(+item) === 'number'){
            overallScore.push(item)
        }
    }
```

Comment: а зачем там + ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ видимо, из-за`"sport" : "3"`

Comment: да, значение sport перевожу в number

Comment: @lev `if (!isNaN(item)) { ...`

Answer (score 3):

проблема в том, что `+` пытается превратить **что угодно** в число. если это невозможно, то оно его превращает в `NaN` (**not a number**). а `NaN` - это сущность, которая так же имеет тип `number`. то есть, Вы в любом случае будете получать тип `number`.

попробуйте проверить вот на этом:

```
const test = +"lolo";  // NaN
console.log(typeof test); // number
```

под Вашим вопросом в комментариях коллега @Yaant предложил отличное решение, по-этому не буду повторяться